# Install Play 2.0 thru macports

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, macports

When I do `sudo port install play` my computer installs `Play 1.2.5`. How do I install `Play 2.0` using `macports`? I am using `Mountain Lion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=play, it doesn't look like there is a Play 2.0 installer. If there was, it would likely be `sudo port install play2`